# How to send JSON data from csv file in POST method?

Tags: json, csv, jmeter, load-testing

In my project I am using Jmeter for load testing.
I have created a test plan as follows:

1. Login to the application using a csv file which has 10 unique username and password (successfully done)
2. A regular expression extractor will get the session id from the response which will be used in the next sampler for submitting a request. (sessionId extracted successfully)
3. The next sampler will submit a request. This sampler accepts two parameters: sessionId & licenseRequest. A little details for the java-script is as follows:

   ```
   url: "groovy/enqueue",
   type: "POST",
   global: false,
   data: {sessionId: uSessionId, licenseRequest: JSON.stringify(requestJSON) },
   dataType: "text",
   ```

For submitting the request I have created a csv file.
The csv is similar like this:

**Entry 1:**
`{"activations":["<activation-code>","<activation-code>"],"email":"<emailIdofUser>","csvEntries":[{"model":"<modelname>","serial":"<serialNo>"}],"comment":"testing jmeter"}`

What I have found out that while submitting the request in th second sampler the post request is malformed:

```
POST data:
sessionId=vZNjFjW38cid&licenseRequest=%3CEOF%3E
```

As you can see the licenseRequest's value is not correct. It is sending the EOF, which is not desired.

[image]

Comment: It worked when I passed the csv entry as a parameter in the sampler. The purpose for using the csv is to I want to feed lots of submitRequest to different user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that you have the [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) `Recycle on EOF` and `Stop Thread on EOF` values correctly:

- if you plan to iterate over the file more than once you must set `Recycle on EOF = True` (i.e. instruct jmeter to move back to the top of the CSV file);
- set `Stop Thread on EOF = False` if you are using a loop controller, `Stop Thread on EOF = True` if you are using a while controller and want to stop after reading the whole csv dataset;
- in case if you need that each of N threads reads and uses single and unique line from csv-file you have to set `Sharing mode: Current thread group` for CSV Data Set Config (number of csv-entries should be in this case the same as threads number, or `Recycle on EOF? False` should be set otherwise);
- in case if you need that each of N threads reads and uses all lines from csv-file you have to set `Sharing mode: Current thread` for CSV Data Set Config.

Don't forget to look into jmeter.log or use [Log Viewer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) to detect any issues with csv usage.

---

The simplest case is like the following:

```
Test Group
Number of Threads = 10
    CSV Data Set Config (User Logins)
    Filename: ... (your csv-file should have 10 entries)
    Recycle on EOF = False
    Stop Thread on EOF = True
    Sharing Mode = All threads
    CSV Data Set Config (License Request)
    Filename: ... (your csv-file should have 10 entries)
    Recycle on EOF = False
    Stop Thread on EOF = True
    Sharing Mode = All threads
    Login Sampler
    License request Sampler
```

This will produce 10 threads each with separate login-entry and license-request-entry from csv's.

Comment: My goal of the test plan is as follows:
1. User will login into the application. A set of valid username,password will be provided using a csv(e.g. no of csv entries 10)
2. A regex extractor will get the user session id from the response and will submit a new request with the session id captured from each users. The submit request will also come from another csv file (which is actually json values)
3. After submitting the request user will log out (http request) using their session id.
Could you please suggest any best practices for developing the above mentioned test plan?

Comment: Well, I've got already your scenario from your question. I've pointed the moments you have to look into and configure properly to get your scenario working as you want. See answer updated with possible schema.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thanks