# Manipulating json string with Jmeter

Tags: json, post, request, jmeter

Im new to Jmeter and web applications at all, I need some help with a json post.

I have an application with a POST request that sends a json string to save the data that was created/changed.

Here an example of the json code that is sent through the POST request

```
{"ID":0,"Description":"Test 1"}
```

With that the first user will create a new registry "Test 1", the second user will create another registry with the same description. I´d like to be able to set the ID and Description info as variables to manipulate them. When the post receive ID 0 is to make a new registry, when It receive an specific ID is to update that registry.

I´m trying to simulate some scenarios that user 1 create, user 2 update or user 1 create, user 2 create different. Things like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send JSON data from csv file in POST method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938950/how-to-send-json-data-from-csv-file-in-post-method)

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to update the ID and the Description @ run time,

Keep the ID and the Description in a CSV file. (something like below)

```
0, Test1
0, Test1
1, Test2
```

Use "CSV Data Set Config" (under Config element) to read the CSV file. update the file name and enter "ID,Description" in the variable names.

Update the JSON as

```
{"ID":${ID},"Description":"${Description}"}
```

This approach will read the data from CSV and update the JSOn @ run time and send the request.

first thread / loop will take the first row and second thread will take the second row.

It should work..let me know if anything.